# Give access to the Play Store in a WiFi HotSpot

Tags: google-play, wifi, hotspot

One of our hotel clients provide free WiFi to its guests with a Hot Spot, however, there are available only a few URL to access them freely (such as Facebook or the website of the hotel) and if you need more access you should log in.

We have developed the App for the hotel and one of its features is that if you open the App it gives you a complete access to the hotel WiFi, so you can navigate to any page you want.

Therefore, it is necessary that the guests can download the app through the Play Store without being logged in to the hotel WiFi, so the guest can download the App and get the access immediately.

We have a trace of the URL that calls the Play Store for search and downloading the App and we have set the Hot Spot to allow access to this URL, however, the Play Store tells us that we have no connection.

What URL should we need to enable in our Hot Spot for the Play Store to work properly?

These are the routes that have enabled:

> .ggpht.com
>
> android.clients.google.com
>
> play.google.com

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer leed us in the right direction, we made a trace of the Play Store and we open del IP range.

[Give access to the AppStore in a WiFi HotSpot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39369248/give-access-to-the-appstore-in-a-wifi-hotspot)

Happy coding.